# Graph with loops but without multiple lines

Tags: graph-theory

In the book Graph Theory by Frank Harary we have the following statement

> If both loops and multiple lines are permitted,  we have a pseudograph.

My question is as follows.What if we dont have multiple lines but we have loops only?. Can we call them, even then, pseudograph or some special name or nothing

Comment: If you interpret "are permitted" as meaning there *may* but don't *have to* be, then by Harary's definition the no multiple lines but some loops ase would still be a pseudograph.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit tricky because of different naming systems.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Graph "Sometimes, graphs are allowed to contain loops, which are edges that join a vertex to itself. For allowing loops, the above definition must be changed by defining edges as multisets of two vertices instead of two-sets. Such generalized graphs are called graphs with loops or simply graphs when it is clear from the context that loops are allowed."

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph "For some authors, the terms pseudograph and multigraph are synonymous. For others, a pseudograph is a multigraph that is permitted to have loops. "

So, for instance at my graph theory courses I was taught that it is ok for ${graph}$ to have loops, but once they have multiple edges then I would call it pseudograph.